# Why I cannot get the same answer if I do substitution with $x=a \cos\theta$ for $\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$ compared with substitution $x=a \sin\theta$?

Tags: integration

Why I cannot get the same answer if I do substitution with $x=a \cos\theta$ for $\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$ compared with substitution $x=a \sin\theta$?

$\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx = \int \sqrt{a^2 - a^2 \cos^2 \theta} d\theta = \int a \sin\theta d\theta = \int a \sin\theta(-a \sin\theta)d\theta = -a^2 \int sin^2 \theta = -a^2[\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4}]+C$

However, the correct answer seems to be $a^2(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4}) + C$

Comment: I think that it is so because $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$

Comment: Shouldn't the antiderivative have $\theta$ instead of $x$?

Comment: You were integrating in terms of $\theta$ so your antiderivative should contain $\theta$, not $x$.

Comment: @player3236 Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I(x)$ integral done by two different methods yields $I_1(x), I_2(x)$. These two differ only  by a constant independent of $x$: $I_1(x)-I_2(x)=$Cosnstant, eventually.
In @lab Bhattacharjee 's answer above
$$I_2(x)=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\frac{a^2}{2} \cos^{-1}(x/a)$$
and$$I_2(x)=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{2} \sin^{-1}(x/a)$$
So $$I_1(x)-I_2(x)=\frac{a^2}{2}[-\cos^{-1}(x/a)-\sin^{-1}(x/a)]=-\frac{a^2\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Method**$\#1:$

If $\theta=\arccos\dfrac xa=\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin\dfrac xa,$

$\cos\theta=\dfrac xa,0\le\theta\le\pi$

$$dx=-a\sin\theta\ d\theta\text{ and }\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=a\sin\theta$$

$$\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\ dx=-\int a^2\sin^2\theta\ d\theta=\dfrac{a^2}2\int(\cos2\theta-1)\ d\theta=\dfrac{a^2\sin2\theta}4-\dfrac{a^2\theta}2$$

Now $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta=?$

**Method**$\#2:$

If $\theta=\arcsin\dfrac xa,$

$\sin\theta=\dfrac xa,-\dfrac\pi2\le\theta\le\dfrac\pi2$

$$dx=a\cos\theta\ d\theta\text{ and }\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=a\cos\theta$$

$$\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\ dx=\int a^2\cos^2\theta\ d\theta=\dfrac{a^2}2\int(\cos2\theta+1)\ d\theta=\dfrac{a^2\sin2\theta}4+\dfrac{a^2\theta}2$$

Now $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta=?$